# Can we adjust the borders of buttons in Android?

Tags: android, image, button, imageview

I have a requirement where two buttons are side-by-side but are 'Rhombus' in shape. I'm trying to use the two images and place a buttons on top of them with the buttons being transparent so that the images may show up.

But the buttons are rectangular in shape. Is there a way to change the shape of the buttons to be a rhombus so that the user clicks on the correct areas in the button layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the shape of a View.  Every view is rectangular by design.  A better way of dealing with this would be to assign a specific shape background to your buttons.  Then clicking anywhere within the shape of your background would still be inside the button, although clicking just outside would still be considered the click of the button.  But at least clicking anywhere inside the shape would register as a click.